# Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401 and i used cross origin plugin

Tags: java, angularjs, cors

```
var req = {
                method: 'GET',
                url: holaRootUrl + action,
                headers: {

                   'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + $rootScope.accessToken
                },
                params:params
            }

            $http(req).success(function () {
                console.log("yes you have done it");
            }).error(function () {
                console.log("oopsss");
            });
```

this is what I got :`Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code` 401

Comment: 401 is `unathorized` do you have some http authentication? what's your backend?

Comment: `'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + $rootScope.accessToken` so I assume that you do have authentication, it has to be disabled for `OPTIONS` call

Comment: my back end is rest full web service , yes and i'm using Oauth2 ,

Comment: i noticed when i  made something like  String authString = requestContext.getHeaderString("Authorization"); it is return null !!?

Comment: Probably that's the cause, you should check if the method is `OPTIONS` and then return 200 OK and handle POST and GET separately

Comment: @maurycy is right, return 2xx or 3xx range status on your options request and you will be fine.

Comment: Sorry how can i check if this method is option or not !?

Comment: @lin I'm afraid 3xx aren't the perfect solution, i.e. chrome cancels OPTIONS with 302
Mohamed that's why I asked what kind of back end you use, java, javascript, php, .net?

Comment: My back end is java

Comment: @maurycy oowww, does it? Learned, thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the discussion in comments, the issue got narrowed to authentication on `OPTIONS` calls and in result sending the `401 Unathorized` code.

I don't know JAVA to well but try something like this before applying authentication check

```
if ( request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS") ) {
    resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    return;
}
```

Comment: if (requestContext.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
            requestContext.abortWith(Response
                    .status(Response.Status.OK)
                    .entity("abort.") } 
                    .build());